# MongoDB updateOne with upsert not inserting document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, upsert

I have a nodejs Discord bot that is trying to update/insert a document in a mongodb (v4.2.2). I've done this many times, but for some reason, this particular function is just not working and I cannot find my error.

```
quit: async function ( memberId ) {
    console.log (memberId)  //checks out
    let member = await client.db('players').collection('suspensions').findOne({ _id: memberId }) 
    console.log(member) //null
    if ( !member ) {
        console.log('member not found') //i see this, so I know it's trying
        try {
            client.db('players').collection('suspensions').updateOne(
                { _id: memberId },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "quit.tier": 0,
                        "minor.tier": 0,
                        "moderate.tier": 0,
                        "major.tier": 0,
                        suspended: 0,
                        quitter: 0
                    }
                },
                {
                    $currentDate: {
                        ends: true,
                    }
                },
                { upsert: true }).then( (err, results) => {
                    console.log('in callback') //i see this, so I know it's getting here
                    if (err) console.log(err) //see error below
                    console.log(results)  //undefined
                    return
                }
            )
        }
        catch ( e ) {
            console.log (e) //never gets here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

error output:

```
CommandResult {
  result: { n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 },
  connection: Connection {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      commandStarted: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandFailed: [Function (anonymous)],
      commandSucceeded: [Function (anonymous)],
      clusterTimeReceived: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    id: 1,
    address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
    bson: BSON {},
    socketTimeout: 360000,
    monitorCommands: false,
    closed: false,
    destroyed: false,
    lastIsMasterMS: 1,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(description)]: StreamDescription {
      address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
      type: 'Standalone',
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 8,
      maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
      maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
      maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
      compressors: []
    },
    [Symbol(generation)]: 0,
    [Symbol(lastUseTime)]: 1589941704648,
    [Symbol(queue)]: Map(0) {},
    [Symbol(messageStream)]: MessageStream {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      bson: BSON {},
      maxBsonMessageSize: 67108864,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(buffer)]: [BufferList]
    },
    [Symbol(stream)]: Socket {
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'localhost',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      readable: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      writable: true,
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: null,
      _server: null,
      timeout: 360000,
      _peername: [Object],
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 229,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TCP],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: Timeout {
        _idleTimeout: 360000,
        _idlePrev: [TimersList],
        _idleNext: [Timeout],
        _idleStart: 5042,
        _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: null,
        _destroyed: false,
        [Symbol(refed)]: false,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 243,
        [Symbol(triggerId)]: 229
      },
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0
    },
    [Symbol(ismaster)]: {
      ismaster: true,
      maxBsonObjectSize: 16777216,
      maxMessageSizeBytes: 48000000,
      maxWriteBatchSize: 100000,
      localTime: 2020-05-20T02:28:24.642Z,
      logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: 30,
      connectionId: 2794,
      minWireVersion: 0,
      maxWireVersion: 8,
      readOnly: false,
      ok: 1
    }
  },
  message: BinMsg {
    parsed: true,
    raw: <Buffer 3c 00 00 00 0b 37 04 00 08 00 00 00 dd 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 10 6e 00 00 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 01 6f 6b ... 10 more bytes>,
    data: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 27 00 00 00 10 6e 00 00 00 00 00 10 6e 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 00 00 00 00 00 01 6f 6b 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 00>,
    bson: BSON {},
    opts: { promoteLongs: true, promoteValues: true, promoteBuffers: false },
    length: 60,
    requestId: 276235,
    responseTo: 8,
    opCode: 2013,
    fromCompressed: undefined,
    responseFlags: 0,
    checksumPresent: false,
    moreToCome: false,
    exhaustAllowed: false,
    promoteLongs: true,
    promoteValues: true,
    promoteBuffers: false,
    documents: [ [Object] ],
    index: 44
  },
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

Note that I am able to run the similar updateOne command from the mongo UI and it inserts just fine:

````
> use players
switched to db players
> db.suspensions.updateOne({ _id: '313389427671957504' }, { $set: { "quit.tier": 0, "minor.tier": 0,"moderate.tier": 0,"major.tier": 0,suspended: 0,quitter: 0 } }, { upsert: true })
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "matchedCount" : 0,
        "modifiedCount" : 0,
        "upsertedId" : "313389427671957504"
}
> db.suspensions.find()
{ "_id" : "313389427671957504", "major" : { "tier" : 0 }, "minor" : { "tier" : 0 }, "moderate" : { "tier" : 0 }, "quit" : { "tier" : 0 }, "quitter" : 0, "suspended" : 0 }```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to the [updateOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-updateOne) function are (query document, update document, options document, callback function).

In the updateOne call in the provided code, you have 4 arguments, but 2 of them are update documents.  Try combining them into a single document like:

```
 client.db('players').collection('suspensions').updateOne(
                { _id: memberId },
                {
                    $set: {
                        "quit.tier": 0,
                        "minor.tier": 0,
                        "moderate.tier": 0,
                        "major.tier": 0,
                        suspended: 0,
                        quitter: 0
                    },
                    $currentDate: {
                        ends: true,
                    }
                },
                { upsert: true })
```

Answer (score 1):

**$current_date and $set** operator will come in the same object in the query, in your query you put them in 2 different objects

Below is the working code

```
quit: async function ( memberId ) {
    console.log (memberId)  //checks out
    let member = await client.db('players').collection('suspensions').findOne({ _id: memberId }) 
    console.log(member) //null
    if ( !member ) {
        console.log('member not found') //i see this, so I know it's trying
        try {
            client.db('players').collection('suspensions').updateOne(
                { _id: memberId },
                {   
                    $currentDate: {
                        ends: true,
                    },
                    $set: {
                        "quit.tier": 0,
                        "minor.tier": 0,
                        "moderate.tier": 0,
                        "major.tier": 0,
                        suspended: 0,
                        quitter: 0
                    }
                },
                { upsert: true }).then( (err, results) => {
                    console.log('in callback') //i see this, so I know it's getting here
                    if (err) console.log(err) //see error below
                    console.log(results)  //undefined
                    return
                }
            )
        }
        catch ( e ) {
            console.log (e) //never gets here
            return;
        }
    }
}
```